# Link Lists not showing up in search

Tags: sxa, solr

I am working on the search for my site.  It is working as expected for the most part, but I noticed that if I add a link list with multiple links, the text from those links does not show up in the search.  I have tried going to the link and link list template and letting them inherit the searchable template.  I then published everything and rebuilt the indexes, and the links are still not showing up in the search.  Everything I am doing is OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the text from the links set in a link list are indexed by default. SXA comes with a computed field `sxacontent` which is aggregating all texts from all fields of an item and uses the implementation in `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.AggregatedContent`. It is configured in  `\App_Config\Include\z.Foundation.Overrides\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Solr.config`.

If you take a look using any decompiler in the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.dll there is a method which extracts the values for each field

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<object> ExtractTextFields(Item item, ProviderIndexConfiguration config)
    {
      if (!config.DocumentOptions.ExcludedTemplates.Contains(item.TemplateID.ToString()))
      {
        item.Fields.ReadAll();
        foreach (SitecoreItemDataField sitecoreItemDataField in this.GetNonStandardField(item))
        {
          if (IndexOperationsHelper.IsTextField((IIndexableDataField) sitecoreItemDataField) && !config.DocumentOptions.ExcludedFields.Contains(sitecoreItemDataField.Id.ToString()))
          {
            string fieldValue = config.FieldReaders.GetFieldValue((IIndexableDataField) sitecoreItemDataField) as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValue))
              yield return (object) fieldValue;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The method IndexOperationsHelper.IsTextField is determining what field will be indexed by default:

```
private static readonly List<string> TextFieldTypes = new List<string>()
    {
      "Single-Line Text",
      "Rich Text",
      "Multi-Line Text",
      "text",
      "rich text",
      "html",
      "memo",
      "Word Document"
    };
```

You would need to add your custom implementation and override the configuration node `